# Retriveing the intersection of matrices

Tags: matlab

```
whos.exit  whos    condition1  result
 650        452      1          0
 654        456      0          0
 254        650      1          1
 785        412      1          0
 756        654      1          1
            744      0          0
            125      1          0
            985      1          0
            ...      ...        ...
```

I wish obtain the result matrix.
Result matrix contains all "whos" which satify the condition1 and are present whos.exit but in no particular order. Note: all elements in whos.exit are unique and the result of whos(condition1) will give unique whos.

Comment: Is your data a cell or a matrix? If matrix, how can you have empty rows?

Comment: matrix, which empty rows you say?

Comment: I (incorrectly) assumed that your data was in a matrix. Not four separate variables. If that was the case, the last three rows of `whos.exit` would have been empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ismember`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) -

```
result = ismember(whos,whos.exit).*condition1
```

Or [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
result = any(bsxfun(@eq,whos,whos.exit.'),2).*condition1
```

Since `whos` is an [in-built command in MATLAB](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html), I would suggest using some other variable name there as a matter of *good practice*.

Comment: How would the `bsxfun` version work on the elements after `756` i.e. where `whos.exit` is empty?

Comment: @kkuilla Well I am creating singleton dimension there with that transpose `.'` on `whos.exit`. So, `whos` and `whos.exit` don't have to be of the same lengths.

Comment: @kkuilla, by checking each `whos.exit` element with every element of `whos`, and accepting if any of them is `true`, +1 for the solution

Comment: @SanthanSalai I knew that but my question was more due to the fact that I supposed that the data was in a matrix rather than four separate values. These things happen when reading too quickly..

Comment: @kkuilla yeah the question was little bit unclear.. i got the question only after reading Divakars answer LOL

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`intersect`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html)

```
intersect(whos.exit,whos.*condition1)
ans =

   650
   654
```

---

Or if you want a binary array (not as elegant as[`ismember`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) though)

```
A=zeros(size(whos.exit,1),1);
[~,~,iwe]=intersect(whos,whos.exit);
A(iwe) = 1;
A.*c1
ans =

   0
   0
   1
   0
   1
   0
   0
   0
```

#### or

```
[~,~,iwe]=intersect(whos,whos.exit);
sum((((c1.*whos.exit)./whos.exit(iwe)')==1)')'

ans =

   0
   0
   1
   0
   1
   0
   0
   0
```

---

#### Details

Find the indices in `whose.exit` whose values are in both arrays.

```
[~,~,iwe]=intersect(whos,whos.exit)
iwe =

   3
   5
```

Find where those values are. I just use a division because a value divided by itself will show a `1` and that tells us where the values are. Each row represents the value(s) we are looking for and the column the location of this value. The first value `(whos.exit(iwe(1)))` is location at position `3` and the second `(whos.exit(iwe(2)))`  is location at position `5`.

```
(((c1.*whos.exit)./whos.exit(iwe)')==1)'
ans =

   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
```

The we just sum and transpose that to get the binary array

```
sum((((c1.*whos.exit)./whos.exit(iwe)')==1)')'
ans =

   0
   0
   1
   0
   1
   0
   0
   0
```

Comment: I think you can use the second output from intersect to get a binary array like `result`.

Comment: @Divakar I didn't realise a binary array was required. I think the question is a bit unclear. The code to generate the binary array became a little complicated than I expected though but almost a one-liner :-)....

Comment: Good job on explaining. This could be a bit easier to follow maybe - `[~,exclusive_idx] = setdiff(whos1,whos.exit);
out = condition1;
out(exclusive_idx) = 0;`.

Comment: @Divakar Yes, I added a simpler version based on your suggestion. Can't believe I didn't see that.